# Why does the msdn example for DataSet.ReadXml (stream) not work for .NET 1.0?

Tags: xml, compact-framework, sql-server-ce, filestream, .net-1.0

I'm wondering if using a stream would be faster to read an XML file and then insert into SQLCE (as opposed to reading the data from a file). So, I tried this code:

```
DataSet dset = new DataSet("New DataSet");
System.IO.FileStream streamRead = new System.IO.FileStream(filePathName, System.IO.FileMode.Open);
dset.ReadXml(streamRead);
```

...from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/55hehd8c(v=vs.80).aspx

...but get these compile errors:

"*Argument '1': cannot convert from 'System.IO.FileStream' to 'System.Xml.XmlReader'*"
-and:
"*The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.DataSet.ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader)' has some invalid arguments*"

Is it because the earliest example (the link above) is for .NET 2.0, and I am stuck with 1.0? IOW, the stream overload was not available in 1.0?

### UPDATE

I also wanted to test this:

```
StringReader sr = new StringReader(filePathName);
DataSet dset = new DataSet("duckBills");
dset.ReadXml(sr);
```

...from here: http://knowdotnet.com/articles/datasetreadxml.html, but got a similar err msg; I think being stuck on .NET 1.0 is likely my problem...

Comment: At the bottom of the MSDN page you linked it says "Version Information ... .NET Compact Framework ... Supported in: 2.0" so I think you're out of luck if you are limited to 1.1

Comment: Ah yes; I reckon my suspicion was correct. "Dang it!" as Kip Dynamite said in response to the Tupperware splintering into untold sharp shards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

[new XmlTextReader(Stream)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cssfs8c4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
DataSet dset = new DataSet("New DataSet");
using (System.IO.FileStream streamRead = new System.IO.FileStream(filePathName, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
{
    XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(streamRead);
    dset.ReadXml(reader);
}
```

Comment: Although I get, "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Xml.XmlTextReader' to 'System.IDisposable'" and had to replace "var" with "XmlTextReader", I will work around that and try this out...

Comment: Fixed. It didn't implement IDisposable in ancient times!